# Теряется форматирование TextView при добавлении текста

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Стоит задача добавлять в TextView куски текста со своим форматированием.
Например пишу:

```
myTextView2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+mytitle+"</b><br>"));
```

Позже хочу в него же добавить еще текста, перебирая в цикле массив:

```
for (int k=0; k<abzacyStringArray.length-1; k++){
            myTextView2.setText(myTextView2.getText().toString() + Html.fromHtml(abzacyStringArray[k]+"<br>"));
        }
```

Как не потерять форматирование, кроме варианта писать сначала все в одну HTML строку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавлять текст не переназначая его так:

```
 myTextView2.append(Html.fromHtml(abzacyStringArray[k]+"<br>"));
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method...

Comment: @maratsoft, см. обновлённый ответ

Comment: во так сработало, спс! Кстати, <br> не закрывающий д.б., я в своем вопросе уже поправил)

Comment: @maratsoft,пж-та) В ответе тоже поправил. Вы, кстати, и сами можете любой вопрос/ответ править. Правда, пока не будет соответствующего кол-ва репутации, правки надо будет ещё утвердить.